# Mocking, assert_called with, in python

Tags: python, mocking, assert

I need to make sure a function is being called with a specific argument in python. I have mocked this function out using magic mock.

```
self.function = MagicMock()
self.function(subject= "Hello World")
```

Does something exist along the lines of

```
self.function.assert_called_with("Hello World")
```

or

```
self.function.assert_called_with(subject= "Hello World")
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been poking around the mock docs and it doesn't seem like any of the assert statements will work for me.

EDIT: I added some debug output

When I attempt to debug, I see

```
AssertionError: 
Expected call: mock('Hello World')
Actual call: mock('thing i dont care about', 'Hello World', 'thing i dont care about')
```

So apparently, the function is being called, but the assert is acting weird. It doesn't recognize "Hello World" in the list of arguments or something.

EDIT2:

I changed up my code a little bit, and it still isn't matching properly

```
self.function = MagicMock(field1 = None, field2 = None, subject = None, field4 = None)

#later on...
self.function(1,2,"Hello World",4)  #these params will not always be 1,2,4 .. I made them so to
                                     #show an example

#even further down the road
self.function.assert_called_with(ANY, ANY, "Hello World", ANY)
```

Something like this isn't working for me either. Still getting the error

```
AssertionError: 
Expected call: mock(<ANY>, <ANY>, "Hello World", <ANY>)
Actual call: mock(1,2,"Hello World", 4)
```

Again, I couldn't just do something like

How does "ANY" correspond to pattern matching an argument?

Comment: obviously my actual code is much more complex than this, but this was to convey the general problem I am having.

Comment: what's your problem? you code works.

Comment: I need something that will detect one parameter, out of several.
The thing it is saying the mock is being called with is

    mock("First Thing", "Second Thing", "Hello World", etc...)

which means it doesn't match my subject.

Comment: again, I need to detect one parameter out of several

Comment: Still not sure that I get what you exactly want. Can you update your question with given and expected behaviour? Do you want to check that `subject= "Hello World"` is among args, or any of list of args is present?

Comment: I want to check that subject= "Hello World" is present in the list of args that the mock was called with. So I want to assert basically that we call it with (don't care, don't care, "Hello World", don't care, don't care)

Comment: Your example, `self.function(subject= "Hello World")` contradicts your error, as no `'thing i dont care about'` can be found in former.

Comment: exactly. Suppose I was only calling the function with that one parameter though (ie: the others are set to None or something).

Comment: sorry :/ can't. At work

Comment: it is the content filter :/ I clicked the link and it took me to a "you can't go there" screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written works perfectly as you had intended. Taking out the self, here is a simplified version-

```
func = mock.MagicMock()
func(subject="Hello World")
# assert that func was indeed called with subject="Hello World"
# this goes well since it was indeed called with "Hello World"
func.assert_called_with(subject="Hello World") 
# this fails since func was not called with "Bye World"
AssertionError: Expected call: mock(subject='Bye World')
Actual call: mock(subject='Hello World') 
# The mock also distinguishes between calls with positional and keyword arguments
# so func(subject="Hello World") is not same as func("Hello World") w.r.t.
# the assert statements
```

Thats what is expected. So if you want to ensure that the mock function was indeed called with expected arguments, simply use-

```
func(key=<args>)
func.assert_called_with(key=<args>)
```

or

```
func(<args>)
func.assert_called_with(<args>)
```

Just remember to match the function signature in call and assert.